# Should exceptions be case classes?

Tags: scala, exception, case-class

Should my custom exception types be `case class`es?

On the plus side, I get extractors.

On the minus side, I get incorrect equality semantics. But I can avoid that by overriding `equals`.

So does it make sense, at a conceptual level, to make them `case class`es?

Comment: What I am looking for would be a macro which just creates a case-class like companion with apply and unapply, but without everything else, especially without the inheritance restrictions. This would be useful in other places too.

Answer (score 39):

This is very subjective of course, but in my opinion it is good practice to have exception classes as case classes.
The main rationale being that when you catch an exception, you are doing pattern matching, and  case classes are much nicer to use in pattern matching.
Here's an example that takes advantage of the ability to use the full power of pattern matching in a catch block, when using a case class exception:

```
object IOErrorType extends Enumeration {
  val FileNotFound, DeviceError, LockedFile = Value
}
case class IOError(message: String, errorType: IOErrorType.Value) extends  Exception(message)

def doSomeIO() { throw IOError("Oops, file not found!", IOErrorType.FileNotFound)  }

try {
  doSomeIO()
} catch {
  case IOError( msg, IOErrorType.FileNotFound ) =>
    println("File not found, please check the path! (" + msg + ")")
}
```

In this example, we have only one exception, but it contains an `errorType` field for when you want to know the exact error type that occurred (usually this is modelled through a hierarchy of exception, I'm not saying this is better or worse, the example is just illustrative). Because the `IOError` is a case class I can simply do `case IOError( msg, IOErrorType.FileNotFound )` to catch the exception only for the error type `IOErrorType.FileNotFound`. Without the extractors that we get for free with case classes, I would have to catch the exception everytime, and then rethrow in case I'm actually not interested, which is definitely more verbose.

You say that case classes give you incorrect equality semantics. I don't think so. **You**, as the writer of the exception class gets to decides what equality semantics makes sense. After all when you catch an exception, the catch block is where you decide which exceptions to catch usually based on the type alone, but could be based on the value of its fields or whatever, as in my example. The point is that the equality semantics of the exception class has little to do with that.

Answer (score 21):

One common idiom you lose by making exceptions case classes is the pattern of creating a subclass hierarchy of exceptions with subclassing used to indicate greater specificity of the error condition.    Case classes can't be subclassed.

Comment: Good point. But if needed you can still create a hierarchy of abstract exception types (traits or abstract classes) and have all the leaf types be case classes. This requires that you "own" the whole hierarchy though, or in other words that client code is not supposed to extends your exception classes. If that's not the case then using case classes for exceptions might not be the best idea indeed.

Comment: Although you could define a common trait

Comment: case classes can be subclassed. Only restriction is that the subclass can not be a case class itself.

Comment: Yes but then you have a somewhat inconsistent hierarchy with some exceptions up in the hierarchy that can be caught using extractors and others down the hierarchy that have to ne caught by type. Better introduce common traits as suggested by 0__. Provided this is worth the trouble, as you might actually simply prefer to avoid case classes if you really have an **open** and **non flat** exception hierarchy (this is a valid question given that what you gain from case classes here is certainly not vital, so It is not as clear cut and people will make different choices in different situations).

Comment: As in normal case classes, you can create some marker traits, and make heirarchy of them.

Answer (score 5):

I like the answer from Régis Jean-Gilles. But if you have a good reason to not make a case class (see answer of Dave Griffith), you can archieve the same as in the sample above with a normal class and unapply:

```
object IOErrorType extends Enumeration {
  val FileNotFound, DeviceError, LockedFile = Value
}
object IOError {
  def unapply(err: IOError): Option[(String, IOErrorType.Value)] = Some(err.message, err.errorType)
}
class IOError(val message: String, val errorType: IOErrorType.Value) extends  Exception(message)

def doSomeIO() { throw new IOError("Oops, file not found!", IOErrorType.FileNotFound) }

try {
  doSomeIO()
} catch {
  case IOError( msg, IOErrorType.FileNotFound ) =>
    println("File not found, please check the path! (" + msg + ")")
}
```